# CSS blending background over another

Tags: css, transparency, blending

I'm looking to blend the background from the first section of my web page under the curved background of the second scection of the webpage. below is the design made with AdobeXD

[desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jaeF.jpg)

This is what i have so far.

```
.landing-header {
background: url("../images/BG1.png") no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: 0px -278px;
background-blend-mode: lighten;
height: 100%;
width:100%;
overflow-y: hidden;
min-width: 400px;
min-height: 732px;}
```

and for the second section

```
.box1 {
background-image: url(../images/NBG_2.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
height: 100%;
width:100%;
min-height: 2183px;}
```

I've tried to move the bottom background image around but it doesn't blend at all here is a section of how it looks at the moment.

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D93Qn.png)

I think it's also worthy to show what the two backgrounds look like so that you know what i'm working with. the second has transparency and shadow over the edges.
[first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5E8ml.jpg)
and
[second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFB0o.jpg)

Here is the html code relevant to the two backgrounds.

```
<div class="landing-header">
<div class="landing-nav">
    <div class="landing-wrapper">
        <a href="#">TRAILER</a>
        <a href="#">UNIQUE FEATURES</a>
        <img class="logo" src="assets/images/LOGO%20ETHERUM.png" alt="logo">
        <a href="#">STARTERS HELP</a>
        <a href="#">PLAY NOW</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="landing-slogan">
    <p class="motto">RSPS TAKEN TO ANOTHER LEVEL</p>
</div>
<div class="landing-welcome">
    <img class="welcome" src="./assets/images/Hero%20Text.png">
    <p>Etherum is the longest active server, over 7 years online offering 
        very high quality content to players,<br>
        expect to see many unique content available only here at Etherum,<br>
        because we know what we are doing!
    </p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="section">
<div class="box1">
<h1 class="separator">TRAILER</h1>
<p>Check out our awesome trailer below to see what makes Etherum different 
than any other RSPS!</p>
<img class="video" src="assets/images/Vídeo.png">
<img class="hero" alt="hero" src="assets/images/HERO1.png"><
</div>
```

Comment: Share your HTML also.

Comment: I think you could just make a wrapper that consumes all sections where should be *background1*

Comment: You could try absolute positioning it possibly, but messing with it in a pen I very much recommend cutting the overlapping image first and foremost.

Comment: Have attatched the html

Comment: background-blend-mode is applied to the backgrounds of the same container, not with what lays under the container itself ;)The 2 backgrounds you want to mix must be from the same container . multiple backgrounds and for each you can apply a different background-blend-mode. the lowest background is the firs declared or the background-color value if any.

Comment: example from earlier commment : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/ZRgyMV . did this answer your question ?

Comment: Hmm i think maybe the most simple thing to do here will be to just manually apply the blend and cut the images in photoshop.